# librdf compiling error, undefined reference to raptor_new_world_internal'

Tags: c++, g++, rdf, raptor2

After I installed raptor (librdf.org) successfully, I run `g++ test.cpp` to compile. But get `raptor2.h: No such file or directory`.

So I copy `/usr/include/raptor2/raptor2.h` to `/usr/include/raptor2.h`, and the error above dismiss. But a new error occur:`` undefined reference to `raptor_new_world_internal' ``.

Can somebody tell me what's in mistake, thank you.. Environment: ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of copying your header file, try

`#include <raptor2/raptor2.h>`

And compile with `g++ test.cpp -lraptor2`. You need to link against the library in order to be able to use it.

Comment: Author of raptor / librdf here.  You should be using `-I/usr/include/raptor2/` to compile with `-lraptor2` to link and `#include <raptor2.h>` in the code.  Relative includes might not work correctly without that.